# Auto increment a duplicate number

Tags: sql-server

I have a database that handles duplicate records by using a duplicate number as part of the primary key. I'm trying to insert some rows that I've recovered off the Audit table. However when I go to insert the records I violate the primary key. (These aren't duplicates however, the field that makes them unique should be factored into the key). My question is, is there a way to auto increment the duplicate number if a violation occurs when I'm inserting a record with an select/insert statement or do I need to take a differnt approach.

```
fieldA nvarchar(255) not null,
fieldB nvarchar(255) not null,
duplicateNbr int not null,
fieldD nvarchar(255) null, /* Should be part of the key */

Table1 
'Dave','Jones','FieldD1'
'Dave', Jones','FieldD2'

 INSERT INTO Table2 (FName, LName, DuplicateNbr, FieldD)
 SELECT FName, LName, 0, FieldD FROM TABLE1
```

Comment: One of the best solutions I know is using SQL Sequences. It has been conceive just to do what you want.

Comment: There are probably dozens of ways.   It's a simple matter of programming.   What have you investigated, and what technique do you not know how to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your SELECT statement on TABLE1, you can use ROW_NUMBER() function with PARTITION BY clause to number duplicate rows in each duplicate set

Following SQL tutorial shows a way of detecting duplicates and deleting them using [SQL Row_Number() with Partition By](http://www.kodyaz.com/articles/delete-duplicate-rows-using-row-number-partition-by-order-by.aspx)

Here is the query

```
INSERT INTO Table2 (fieldA, fieldB, DuplicateNbr, FieldD)
SELECT 
    fieldA, 
    fieldB, 
    duplicateNbr = ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by fieldA, fieldB Order by newid())-1,
    fieldD 
FROM TABLE1
```

I hope it helps,

Answer (score 0):

I would do it using the [merge statement](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb522522(v=sql.105).aspx).

Just generate a new unique id in the "matched" clause and a normal insert, if nothing matches.